# How to read a XML file in batch?

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a xml file containing a line like this:

```
<id>2012-10-19_23-10-04</id>
```

I want to use the batch file to read the xml file, get the content and assign it to a variable.

I know batch is probably not the preferred way to do this, but I am only allowed to use batch in this case.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have a template like this:

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set input="xml.xml"
set output="result.txt"

REM Some Code here:

REM END
```

**I think XML Starlet might be a good tool to start, any ideas how to do this using xmlstarlet?**

Comment: PowerShell might be the better solution, if you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, solve this by using XML Starlet:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in ('XML.EXE sel -t -v "/id" C:\xml.xml') do set var=%%i
echo date is %var%
```

For you reference, download XML starlet from here: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @CodingMaster, search for "XML Starlet" and you will know