# batch file - read xml file and return value

Tags: batch-file

Need to be able to read an xml file and return a value:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<CONFIGSETTINGS>
    <GENERAL>
        <PROGRAM>App/PROGRAM>
        <CURRENCY>GBP</CURRENCY>
        <VERSION>3</VERSION>
        <RELEASE>0</RELEASE>
        <FULLVERSION>24.0.12.123</FULLVERSION>
    </GENERAL>
    <WEBLINKS>
```

...............

Need to be able to pull out the full version number and place in a variable in the batch file i.e.: 24.0.12.123

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I need to drive a Ferrari or Lamborghini. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you'll post what you've tried so far to solve this yourself and explain how it's not working, we can probably help you figure it out.

Comment: tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089631/how-to-read-a-xml-file-in-batch

Comment: Tried this: http://corengen.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/reading-values-in-an-xml-configuration-file-from-a-batch-file/

Comment: and some others but neither seem to be able to read the xml file's value - no error just nothing returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=2delims=<>    " %%i in ('type file.xml ^|find "FULLVERSION"') do set "version=%%i"
echo(%version%
endlocal
```

Comment: This returns: FULLVERSION

Comment: May I help you doing copy & paste properly? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code I am running is the same as you have here :)

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Still returns FULLVERSION

Comment: so change `tokens=2` to `tokens=3`. maybe your xml is corrupt :)

Comment: Bingo - what difference does that make?

Comment: `delims=<> ` split the lines in token, from left to right from 1 to x. %%i points to the token. See `for /?` on the command line.